# Color of own messages in chat rooms using Puzzling's theme is too similar to others' messages

Tags: feature-request, design, chat

I chat on several rooms throughout the network. Most rooms I chat on for most sites show one's own messages in a very different color from others' messages, such as blue on non-designed sites and yellow for Super User.

However, on chat rooms parented to this site, the color of one's own messages is only *very slightly* different from that of others' messages (a very light shade of gray, hardly distinguishable from the white color used for others' messages).

Can the background color of one's own chat messages for rooms parented to this site please be made more different from that of others' chat messages (e.g. a darker shade of gray)?

Comment: I mean, doesn't really bother me... sounds cool though. Why do you ask? Any specific reason that caused you to ask?

Comment: Maybe it could be the light green or red used in the Puzzling logo...